# How to add CDATA to xml

Tags: java, web-services

I create a web service to receive xml and convert it to a form and start an approving process.
The code is like below and it work:

```
String formXML="<formid><name>Jack</name><question>badge lost</question></formid>";
tSerialNoz = InvokeProcess(processId, userId,tTransactorDept, formXML, "", tFormOID);
```

the InvokeProcess method is from an imported JAR and I don't have the source code. 
To prevent user input some reserved characters I  modified it a little bit:

```
String formXML="<formid><name>Jack</name><question>badge&lost</question></formid>";
tSerialNoz = InvokeProcess(processId, userId,tTransactorDept, "<![CDATA["+formXML+"]]>", "", tFormOID);
```

and it has error message

> Nested exception: The markup in the document preceding the root
>   element must be well-formed

I wonder is this because InvokeProcess method did some fomatting or my code error? Can anyone help? Thx.

Comment: You should put the `<![CDATA[` inside `<formid>`, not around it. Even better, just around the actual data, not around XML you want to be able to interpret.

Comment: And also, even if done correctly, this simplistic approach won't help much. What if the user input contains the character sequence `]]>`?